# Make fire with a potato, salt, and toothpaste?

Tags: chemistry, video, fire

I saw a video recently that seemed to show a fire being started from a potato, salt, toothpaste, a couple of wires, and what appears to be cotton.

A video showing this is [HERE](http://www.wonderhowto.com/how-to-make-fire-from-potatoes-salt-and-toothpaste-fake-90487/). To summarize, it looks like they:

- cut a potato in half
- cut a rounded out hollow in one half and filled it with a mixture of salt and toothpaste
- put wires through the other half and folded them over so that when the two halves were placed together, the two ends were both in the salt/toothpaste mixture
- put the halves together and put a piece of cotton (or something else) around one of the exposed wire ends coming out of the potato halves
- waited a few minutes and then touched the other wire to the cotton and it started on fire

[HERE](http://www.abovetopsecret.com/forum/thread419289/pg1) is a forum where people are talking about the video and many seem to think it's real.

Is this video showing something possible or was it faked?

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the video and also some information as to what part of the video you think is fake so it is clear in your question what is being addressed (that is try not to make your question dependent on the video).

Comment: @Denys P.: I kind of rewrote this, as I found the video I think you watched along with some references, and think it's a perfectly legitimate question for this site. I see this is your first activity here, and so I hoped to keep your question alive (I believe it's old form would have been closed). Spend some time looking at some other questions so you get a feel for what kind of quality is expected. Welcome to skeptics.SE!

Comment: Argh, I want to jump up and down saying "Fake! Fake!" but there are all these annoying expectations of *evidence* here. Bah. (Exit stage left muttering about both wires being treated identically, so there is no "potential difference", so there is no electrical current, so no spark.)

Comment: What is causing the fire? The potato and the salt? The toothpaste being a fuel?

Comment: I'm quite skeptical, but think the idea is spoofing the fact that you *can* generate current from a potato ([LINK](http://cosmology.berkeley.edu/Education/DEMOS/Potato_Power/Potato_Teacher.html)). But... there's no mention of needing different metals, which is key, and as @Oddthinking pointed out, two of the same wire terminating in the same solution won't do anything. Also, powering an LED != enough potential difference to arc and light a piece of cotton.

Comment: @Ham, watching the video it appears to be sparks and/or heat from the current running between the ends of the wires, that touch the cotton wool.

Comment: @Hendy actually cotton is pretty flamable if it is dry and especially flamable if it has been dipped in alchohol.

Comment: @Chad: if alcohol were involved, then yes, we've got quite a different scenario!

Comment: @Hendy - Its a video and the resolution is not great but I bet if you doused a few cotton balls in a bit of alchohol and lit them them flame would look similar in color and effect.  The lack of soot from the inital flame makes me think that there was some sort of clean burning accelerant anyway.  Cotton burns pretty sooty in my experience

Comment: The half-naked girl clinched it as fake for me. A genuine "hey look what I can do"-chemistry-nerd wouldn't include that. The fire would be fun enough in itself.

Answer (score 3):

[Making electricity from potatoes is nothing new.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemon_battery) However for that to happen you need two different metals (typically copper and zinc). It may have been different metals in these wires, but they don't say so. And you need an acid. Which salt and toothpaste isn't. And it won't be enough electricity to make a spark.

There might be some sort of chemistry happening with starch+salt+something in toothpaste, but I doubt it. And even if it would generate electricity, it surely will not do so if you put both wires in the toothpaste. One needs to go in the potato, the other in the paste.

So this is bogus, without a doubt.

Comment: you don't need a acid just a electrolyte which salt dissolved in a polar liquid (like the water content of the gel toothpaste) IS. but you still need 2 different metals for it to work